# Why was '~' chosen to represent the home directory?

Tags: history, home

I have often wondered why the `~` ([tilde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde)) character represents the home directory of a user.

Is there a reason behind this, or is it just because tilde is an infrequently used character?

Comment: WARNING! Never do this `mkdir '~'` because you *will* forget escaping this `rm -rf ~` (worst day ever)!

Comment: That is why you should use `rmdir`.

Comment: @cprn I knew a phd student who did that to their thesis.

Answer (score 1116, accepted):

[Quoting Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde#Directories_and_URLs):

> On Unix-like operating systems (including BSD, GNU/Linux and Mac OS
>   X), tilde often indicates the current user's home directory: for
>   example, if the current user's home directory is `/home/bloggsj`, then
>   `cd`, `cd ~`, `cd /home/bloggsj` or `cd $HOME` are equivalent. This practice
>   derives from the Lear-Siegler ADM-3A terminal in common use during the
>   1970s, which happened to have the tilde symbol and the word "Home"
>   (for moving the cursor to the upper left) on the same key.

[image: layout of the ADM-3A keyboard]

You can find photos of the Lear-Siegler [ADM-3A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADM-3A) keyboard on [this](https://rollmops.wordpress.com/2006/05/01/vintage-computer/) site.

[image: image of an ADM-3A keyboard]

This terminal is also the [source of the movement commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6553850/499768) used in the `vi` editor: <kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>l</kbd> for left, down, up, right.

Comment: I have also read this is why `Esc` is used to switch modes in `vi`, since the key is easy to reach on this type of keyboard.

Comment: Reading this answer, I just realised why GMail's shortcuts also use 'J' and 'K' for move to previous email and move to next email, respectively!

Comment: How neat would it be to have a keyboard like this!

Comment: @ThomasAhle if your keyboard uses [Cherry-MX keys](http://www.wasdkeyboards.com/index.php/gallery2) then you can do this [quite easily](http://imgur.com/a/oCob1). See also this [reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/zq97e/alright_rvim_win_a_free_vim_keycap_heres_a/) on cherry-mx-vim-keyboard setups.

Comment: Incidentally, what is the `HERE IS` key for?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is relevant: `Some teleprinters had a "Here is" key, which transmitted a fixed sequence 20 or 22 characters [...] This was commonly used to identify a station; the operator could press the key to send the station identifier to the other end`. Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleprinter#.22Here_is.22_key

Comment: That's exactly what the "HERE IS" key is for; it would be useful when many terminals share a serial line to the computer. On the ADM-3A, it was an optional addon board for the RAM to store the identification in. Source: http://vt100.net/lsi/adm3a-om/adm3a-om.pdf

Comment: The next question is why the home key selected to have tilde on it. :)

Comment: And you could really edit fast in Vi on an adm3a. Vim users, it's where it all cameo from....

Comment: @JustinEthier: like many vim users, I always tweak my settings in order to make "CapsLock" behave like "ESC" ("ScrollLock" is a good candidate for the "CapsLock" funcions).

Comment: The "resting point" and "I-know-where-I-am-without-looking-at-the-keyboard point" for my index finger of the right is the `j` key. This is probably why this moving scheme has always been such a pain to learn for me.

Comment: another interresting tidbit: hjkl : look at the shape of those letters: 'j' has a bit going underneath the line ("goes down"), 'k' has a bit going above the line ("goes up"), and 'l' (L) has a big going to the right. Easy way to remember each letter's respective direction. And then "h" is the symetrical of "l" around the "hj" axis... [it does help to remember the motions, trust me ^^]. I believe that's why those letters were used for the "left,down,up,right" directions.

Comment: Is this also the reason why in RegEx, "^" is the start of a string?

Comment: @olivier, that is post-facto reasoning. You can't see these features on the keyboard's capital letters anyway. They are the four adjacent home-row letters under the right hand, that's why the arrows are there. Other "classic" keyboards like the VT52 used them this way as well, iirc. (Of course, using I/K for Up/Down, and J/L for right/left, as many console games did, is ergonomically far more convenient.)

Comment: @alexis, How would you know it's not pre-facto?

Comment: @Pacerier, because the QWERTY keyboard layout is about a hundred years older than CRT screens and arrow keys!

Comment: @jogloran Yeah, 'Here is' was unusual to see. But have you seen 'RUB' & 'REPEAT' at the bottom? What is 'RUB'?

Comment: @AlexStragies RUB is short for RUBOUT, which was what the Delete key  was called on many keyboards of the time.

Comment: @JustinEthier according to [image on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADM-3A#/media/File:KB_Terminal_ADM3A.svg) Esc was where nowadays Tab usually is. (I'm considering remapping this in my Vim...)

Comment: If you happened to notice a strange influx of upvotes today, it's because you've been featured on Hacker News for the third time: https://hn.algolia.com/?query=why%20was%20chosen%20home%20directory&sort=byPopularity&prefix&page=0&dateRange=all&type=story

Comment: Where is the 'any' key?  :-)

Comment: @alexis yes no one in there right mind would invent something as poorly optimised as querty for a CRT (or LCD/OLED/etc) display. Now that we don't have mechanical linkages between keys and printer, there is no need for it. (`',.pyf`)

Comment: another clearer example photo can be found in [Why does vim use hjkl for cursor keys?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/9329/33998)

Answer (score 166):

The <kbd>Home</kbd> key was also used for the tilde character on old terminals. See [here](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/why-vim-uses-hjkl-as-arrow-keys/) for more details.