# Why was '.' chosen to represent the current directory and '..' for parent directory?

Tags: directory, history

After reading this question [Why was '~' chosen to represent the home directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34196/design-question-why-was-chosen-to-represent-the-home-directory), next obvious question on my mind was why '.' and '..' was used to represent current directory and parent directory.

It seems so intuitive now, but any particular reason?

Comment: That questions has been [asked and answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280656/where-does-and-come-from)

Answer (score 18):

I doubt you are going to find as interesting an answer as to the tilde question!

I was not there, but .. is like an ellipsis (...), which makes sense in contexts like `cd ../../../there`.  Also, and especially looking at ye olde terminal keyboard from the tilde case, there are not many eligible characters for this purpose.  You don't need to shift for `.`, either.  It's perfect.

The fact that a dot prefix is used for hidden files might be another reason.  Hidden files are not listed by default by tools such as `ls`, so neither are the essentially redundant `.` and `..`.  Redundant in the sense that there is no point considering them along with other files -- they are certainly useful otherwise.

As it turns out I *may* have it backwards...from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory):

> The notion that filenames preceded by a '.' should be hidden is the
>   result of a software bug in the early days of Unix. When the special
>   '.' and '..' directory entries were added to the filesystem, it was
>   decided that the ls command should not display them. However, the ls
>   program was mistakenly written to exclude any file whose name started
>   with a '.', rather than only files named '.' or '..'.

This does turn out to be useful when programming; since the system does include . and .. in response to `readdir()` type commands (and shell globs), ignoring them and hidden files can be accomplished the same way.

A [different opinion](https://plus.google.com/101960720994009339267/posts/R58WgWwN9jp) about that use value is in the reference for the wikipedia quote. **Of course, the whole story could be apocryphal**...it is a little hard to believe that eg, Dennis Ritchie figured just checking for the first character would be okay.

I disagree with the author vis, it would be better to put hidden configuration files in their own directory rather than give them a universal prefix.  The prefix is much more flexible, allowing for in-tree directives like `.gitignore` and `.htaccess`. Witness that files of that sort also appear together when sorted lexicographically -- **so perhaps this was on purpose after all**.

Answer (score 12):

<sup>Mostly the same answer as [@Panos' on stackoverflow](//stackoverflow.com/a/280765):</sup>

In short, it evolved from `d` and `dd` (the `d`irectory and the `d`irectory's `d`irectory) which were created by users by hand. `d` became *dot*, and those `.` and `..` were created first by the `mkdir` utility (setuid after linking directories was no longer allowed by mere user) and later by the `mkdir`  system call.

Excerpt from an [interview with Ken Thompson](https://web.archive.org/web/20030628155419/http://www.princeton.edu/%7Ehos/mike/transcripts/thompson.htm) (1989-09-06):

> **MSM**: But to the user it would look roughly the same as a hierarchy of directories.
>
> **Thompson**: No, the first one was a DG. In fact, it wasn't even acyclic. If you understand the UNIX file system, it was.... there was
> the I-list, which is a definition of all the files on the system. And
> then some of those files, were directories which just contained name
> and I-number. There's nothing in there that constrains it to a tree.
> So it was not in fact, not hierarchical at all.
>
> **MSM**: I see.
>
> **Thompson**: And we did not restrain it to a tree. We were experimenting with various topologies. What we ended up doing is
> turning into concrete and forcing the topologies that in fact were the
> topologies that came by convention from that system. The... Every time
> we made a directory, by convention we put it in another directory
> called *directory - directory*, which was dd. Its name was dd and that
> all the users directories and in fact most other directories, users
> maintain their own directory systems, had pointers back to dd, and dd
> got shortened into *dot-dot*, and dd was for directory-directory. It
> was the place back to where you could to get to all the other
> directories in the system to maintain this spaghetti bowl. So, I mean
> this tuff in various forms, which was strictly convention in this DG
> implementation of just random set of directories and files got forced
> into a typology that we maintained. When we started writing things
> like file systems checking programs and stuff, the locking of the
> spaghetti bowl directories and finding of disjointed things, I mean
> you'd dissever something and never get it back, because you know you'd
> lost it. Those problems became close to insurmountable, and so in the
> next implementation we forced a typology stronger than that.