# What does the '.' (dot) mean?

Tags: linux

I am getting Linux Training and came across one question that I am unable to find answer of:

What does the `.` mean in `chmod` command?
Eg: `chmod 777 .`

Comment: Welcome to U&L! This is an excellent question for someone new to UNIX/Linux. Thanks for asking, and I hope we can provide helpful information.

Comment: Also related: [Why was '.' chosen to represent the current directory and '..' for parent directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/61984/237982)

Answer (score 7):

`.` represents the current directory.   Your mentioned command will give full permissions to everyone on your current directory.  Similarly `..` represents the parent directory (one directory up from the current).  You can see these files by using `ls -a`