# Difference between 'cd' and 'cd ~'

Tags: cd-command, home

I am wondering, if **cd** alone sends me to my home folder and **cd ~** does the same, why was the ~ added in the first place then?

Is it something specific to BASH or would they behave differently in another Shell?

Comment: Definitely not a duplicate. That question is asking about `cd ~` vs `cd $HOME` vs `cd ~not-tandu`. This question is asking about `cd` vs `cd ~`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `~` can be used for more than just that. Any command can profit from having a shortcut to the home folder. So it is not necessary if you want to cd into your home, but what about `~/.config`?

```
$ cd ~/.config
```

Otherwise you'd have to write out the home path, use the `$HOME` var, or do two `cd`s. Also for copying or moving files:

```
$ cp ~/downloads/some-file some/path/
```

Since most of your files are in the home it's always good to have a shortcut.

Comment: Hi ahilsend, actually my question is more oriented towards why the 2 ways. I already know about ~ using the $HOME variable but, with this is mind, why does "CD" alone also send me to home. Why 2 ways for the same purpose?

Comment: @CYREX My guess would be to save typing for the very common case of wanting to move to your home directory.

Comment: The other use of the `~` is to do `cd ~user/download` to go to an user's download directory.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado: I know it's years late, but since I don't see anyone else mentioning it: to answer your question about why there are two apparently redundant ways to specify the home directory, the real answer is that `cd` doesn't know about `~`.  Tilde expansion is something the shell does before executing the `cd` command.  So `cd` uses a default of `$HOME` if no argument is supplied, otherwise it changes to the directory specified by the argument - and it sees the actual directory path, not the `~` character.

Answer (score 7):

Doing `cd`  is basically calling `cd` with no arguments and in accordance with `cd` behavior "...if dir is not supplied, the  value  of  the  HOME shell variable is the default." (from [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins)). By contrast, `cd ~` is when you supply argument to `cd` command, which happens to be `~` and shell will perform [tilde expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/tilde). As far as going back to user's home directory - there's no difference. In either case, `HOME` environment variable will be queried:

```
$ env 'HOME=/usr' bash -c 'cd;pwd; cd ~;pwd'                                      
/usr
/usr
```

Effectively, this also has no difference from `cd $HOME`. However, whereas `cd` will do one and only thing, tilde can be used to perform other expansions such as `~+` for current working directory.

However, interestingly enough we can `unset HOME` to break `cd` but `~` will still work:

```
$ bash -c 'cd /usr;unset HOME;cd;pwd;cd ~;pwd'                                    
bash: line 0: cd: HOME not set
/usr
/home/xieerqi
```

Why ? Again, [answer in the manual:](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Tilde-Expansion)

> If HOME is unset, the home directory of the user executing the shell is substituted instead. Otherwise, the tilde-prefix is replaced with the home directory associated with the specified login name.

Notice that unsetting is different that making empty variable `HOME=` and does have effect.  Documentation specifically talks about unsetting variable. Making variable equal to empty string has effect opposite to what we'd expect:

```
bash-4.3$ env 'HOME=' bash -c 'cd /usr;set|grep "^HOME"; stat -c "%F" ~;cd;pwd'
HOME=
stat: cannot stat '': No such file or directory
/usr
```

Here you can see that making `HOME` empty string breaks both tilde and `cd` behavior.

---

Tilde and `$HOME` have somewhat of a difference and different reason for existence. `$HOME` is a shell variable, which also co-incidentally happens to be one of the environment variables - and that is available to all programs; in C you would use `environ()` to access that. By contrast, `tilde` is shell-specific syntax which performs tilde expansion, although you can use `wordexp()` function to perform shell-like expansion([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15991320/3701431)) in C as well.

The reason why `~` represents `HOME` has been answered in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/34198/85039): once upon a time the tilde character shared same key with `HOME` on  Lear-Siegler ADM-3A terminal. `HOME` by contrast is environment variable that had purely symbolical meaning and no physical representations.

In addition, the fact that `HOME` is an environment variable allows us to unset it, where as we can't set `~` to something else via simple means.

```
# cd ~ will still work, because ~ is blank, so it's same as just cd
$ bash -c 'unset HOME; echo $HOME; cd ~;pwd'                           

/home/xieerqi
$ env 'HOME=' bash -c 'echo $HOME; cd ~;pwd'                                

/home/xieerqi
```

Notice the blank line where first `echo` outputs the unset variable, and the fact that . By contrast, we can't do stuff like this to tilde:

```
$ bash -c '~=; cd ~;pwd'                                                    
bash: ~=: command not found
/home/xieerqi
$ bash -c '~=$'\0'; cd ~;pwd'                                               
bash: ~=bash: command not found
/home/xieerqi
$ bash -c 'unset ~; cd ~;pwd'                                               
bash: line 0: unset: `/home/xieerqi': not a valid identifier
/home/xieerqi
```

However, altering `HOME` does affect `~`:

```
$ env 'HOME=' bash -c 'echo $HOME; stat ~;'                                 

stat: cannot stat '': No such file or directory
```

In addition, because `~` also works as expansion character, we can do stuff like this to show current working directory:

```
$ bash -c 'cd /etc/;stat -c "%n" ~+'                                        
/etc
```

Whereas if we want to do that via environment variables , we need `PWD`, and `HOME` remains the same, or if you do things like `echo $HOME+` - that's merely string/variable concatenation.  But again, `~+` takes information out of environment variables:

```
$ bash -c 'cd /etc/;PWD="/usr";stat -c "%n" ~+'                             
/usr
```

**NOTE**: the `~+` and `~-` expansions work in `ksh`, but not in `dash`.

---

To answer some of your specific questions:

> Is it something specific to BASH or would they behave differently in another Shell?

No, this should be consistent behavior. `ksh`, `dash`, and `csh` - all behave same with `cd` or `cd ~`.

> why was the ~ added in the first place then ?

I would say convenience and historic reasons as explained in the linked answer about tilde. Eventually, it grew to perform more than just home directory expansion.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless whether you are several folder levels above or below `$HOME`, the commands `cd` and `cd ~` do the same thing and do not differ - it will send you back to your HOME directory.

HOWEVER:
When you are 1 or more folder levels above HOME and you want to go DIRECTLY to a sub-directory 1 or more folder levels below `$HOME`, **the tilde (`~`) comes in handy by saving you keystrokes when used to substitute the text needed to refer to `$HOME` when typing a `cd` command.** For instance;

```
/$ cd    # (or cd ~)
~$ pwd
/home/foo
~$ dir
bar bar2 bar3
~$ cd ..
/$ cd ..
/$ pwd
/
/$ cd /bar3
bash: cd: /bar3: no such file or directory
/$ cd ~/bar3    # (instead of "cd /home/foo/bar3")
~/bar3$ pwd
/home/foo/bar3
```

Answer (score 0):

~ stands for /home/username location, so you save some time when typing. For example cd /home/username/Downloads is the same as cd ~/Downloads, but less typing.
Both commands do the same, change the working directory to that location.

Comment: Not really. E.g. `root`'s home directory is usually outside `/home`