# my home directory appears in my download directory

Tags: ls, rm, special-characters

In my Downloads folder when I run `ls` I see the home directory, and I don't know why, I want to remove it but I am afraid to remove my home folder. Can anyone tell me how I can just remove the home directory in the Downloads folder and keep it in the root folder ?

here you can see a picture of what I get when I run `ls` command in the Downloads directory:

[image]

when I run the command:`ls -la` this what I get:

`-rw------- 1 root root 1024 nov 28 20:24 ~`

Comment: It is just a file called `~`, not actually your home directory.

Comment: What gets returned if you type `echo $HOME`?

Comment: i get returned this:
/home/user

Comment: What does `ls -l ~/Downloads` produce? (I think @Celada is correct, just double-checking)

Comment: it produces this: `-rw------- 1 root    root        1024 nov 28 20:24 ~
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing a file named ~ in the Downloads directory; that symbol also happens to refer to your [home directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/34196/117549), when used at the beginning of an unquoted string ([here is what bash does](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html)).

To remove the file, you have many options; here are two of the simplest:

```
rm ~/Downloads/~
cd ~/Downloads && rm ./~
```

Add the `-i` flag to any of the `rm` commands to have it prompt you before removing the file.

Comment: and if i remove it i will not lose my original home directory  ?

Comment: Correct. Just type one of those two commands